# Puppeteer opens about:blank page sometimes

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler, puppeteer, aliexpress

I have been experiencing this issue from a long time now. I have a web scraper on a Windows VM and I have it set to run every few hours. It works most of the time but a lot of times Puppeteer just opens this page  and not the site or page I want to open.

Why does that happen and what can be the fix for this?

[image]

A simple reproduction for this issue can be this code

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'
import { scheduleJob } from 'node-schedule';

async function run() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    executablePath: chromePath,
    defaultViewport: null,
    timeout: 0,
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--start-maximized'],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
      get: () => false,
    });
  });

  await page.goto('https://aliexpress.com', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
    timeout: 0,
  });
}

run();
scheduleJob('scrape aliexpress', `0 */${hours} * * *`, run);
```

Comment: @ggorlen This is not the first time I am facing this issue. It has happened lots of times with lots of sites and lots of puppeteer versions. I couldn't find any way or answer to this. All I can do is manually restart the node app and then it randomly works.

So I added the reproduction now, maybe that would be helpful. Also, I request if you downvoted the question, please don't. I have no intention to waste someone's time

Comment: This is the latest error it gave to me because it stayed stale after opening the browser
`return new Errors_js_1.TimeoutError(errorMessage);
           ^

TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded`